# How can I push my package's assets into root directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a package with some assets.

```
 vendor/package/src/assets/css|js|img etc.
```

How can I move those assets into root directory after installation or updating?

Also, the second question is, can I do this task with PHP? For example:

```
 Route::get('update/{package_name}', function() {

      //Trigger composer here

 });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an artisan command for that

`php artisan asset:publish vendor/package`

for this to properly work, you'd need to put your assets into a public folder within your vendor package like `vendor/package/public/(css|js|img|...)` and everything will be published to your root under `public/packages/vendor/package/(css|js|img|...)`.

you can specify a path from the root, if you're not using the public folder:

`php artisan asset:publish vendor/package --path="vendor/vendorname/package/src/assets"`

docs: http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-assets (although the path parameter is not mentioned there)

Comment: Okay, this sounds good, but am I allowed to add a --path param and change the target folder?

My application doesn't use a `public` folder.

Comment: Can we call it using `Artisan::call('asset:publish vendor/package', array('--path' => 'vendor/vendorname/package/src/assets'));`

Comment: yes, that would work. i see, you could put that into your boot section. another (not so useful though) possibility would be putting it under composer.json in the *scripts* section with *post-update-cmd*  to be executed upon every composer update - but boot is defs better.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he wants is a different destination folder not the source folder. --path is useful when you have a different source folder I believe.